# In ViewComponent: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, async-await, asp.net-core-2.0

In ViewComponent I got this warning:
(I've used `ASP.NET Core 2`)

> warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run
>   synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await
>   non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work
>   on a background thread.

How can I solve it?

```
public class GenericReportViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
   public GenericReportViewComponent()
   {
   }
   public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(GenericReportViewModel model)
   {
       return View(model);
   }
}
```

***Update:***

in view, I have `@await`:

```
 <div class="container">
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("GenericReport", new GenericReportViewModel() { })
    </div>
```

Comment: Remove the ```async``` from the method definition.

Comment: Which part of the error message is not clear to you? Remove async when you dont do async and use await inside the method when you do

Comment: `InvokeAsync` indeed has no asynchronous operations.  You would either make the method no longer `async` or you would `await` an operation within the method.

Comment: From what you've posted your `InvokeAsync` method isn't actually doing anything asynchronous. You can safely remove `async` and return `IViewComponentResult`.

Comment: *Update: in view, I have @await:* ... but you have no await in `InvokeAsync` body

Comment: @Selvin: It means, I don't need to use async ?

Comment: 1. as Tseng wrote  ... warning is self-explanatory 2. you have already answer

Comment: why you would want it to call with await? does your method contains awaitable method inside of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't use any asynchronous call in the method (there is no `await`), hence the warning. `ViewComponent` has 2 methods `InvokeAsync` and `Invoke`. You should use the synchonous version (`Invoke`) of the `ViewComponent` when there is no asynchrounous calls in the implementation:

```
public class GenericReportViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
   public IViewComponentResult Invoke(GenericReportViewModel model)
   {
       return View(model);
   }
}
```

Here's the documentation section about synchronous work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.2#perform-synchronous-work

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, perhaps because it's just a code dump without any explanation?

Answer (score 3):

You have no `await` methods inside your action `InvokeAsync`

You can safely remove `async` and change return to `IViewComponentResult`

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke(GenericReportViewModel model)
{
   return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't need to be async as you're not doing anything that would benefit from an async operation.  Drop async and Task<>.