# Can anyone explain why the Razor calls InvokeAsync but the class implements Invoke

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, async-await, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I'm familiarising myself someone else's code and she has this in the Index.cshtml:

```
        @if (Model.Type == Group)
        {
            @await Component.InvokeAsync("GroupMessage")
        }
```

and this in the ViewComponent class

```
public class GroupMessageViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

So in the markup, there is an InvokeAsync but the class only implements Invoke.  She isn't at the company any longer so I can't ask her for the reasons behind her design (and I'm probably displaying my ignorance of synchronous/asynchronous!)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use any asynchronous call in the method, there is no `await`. `ViewComponent` has 2 methods `InvokeAsync` and `Invoke`.

So you can only use the synchronous method `InVoke` in your `GroupMessageViewComponent`,Otherwise you will get a warning：

> warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

You can see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56024226/in-viewcomponent-this-async-method-lacks-await-operators-and-will-run-synchro).

You can see about compoents synchronization method here: [Perform synchronous work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0#perform-synchronous-work).